# Polynomial regression (scikit learn), finding roots (Y = 0)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have used scikit learn polynomial regression to fit a polynomial of order 4 to some data. I am interested in finding the roots or in other words at which point the curve crosses the x-axis when y = 0. When I looked at numpy's polynomial class, I found that they have a function called roots to do this. Is there something similar to this with scikit learn?

I have written the code below which checks for change from negative to positive giving me an approximate location of where the curve crosses the x-axis when y = 0. But I want to find if there is a better method.

```
#Equation for reference
YY4 = clf4.intercept_[0] + clf4.coef_[0][1] * XX + clf4.coef_[0][2]*np.power(XX,2) + clf4.coef_[0][3]*np.power(XX,3) + clf4.coef_[0][4]*np.power(XX,4)

def neutralState(Y): #Where Y takes the y-axis values 
for i in range(1,len(Y)):
    if (Y[i-1] < 0 and Y[i] > 0) or (Y[i-1] > 0 and Y[i] < 0): #ignore the very first value
        NS_val = (Y[i])
        NS_index = (i)
        return(NS_val,NS_index) #return the closest value to zero

print(neutralState(YY4))
```

Comment: Maybe you can look in to scipy's `optimize` module and `root_scalar`. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.root_scalar) is the doc